# What is the equivalent of printf for a ".mk" file in Android

Tags: android, makefile

I am trying to print the value of a variable along with a custom string in an ".mk" file in Android, in order to look at the value of the variable.

Below is what I am trying to do:

File: 
abc.mk

Comment:
$(info value of ABC is $(ABC))

But I am not able to compile and get the below error:

*21:02:23 Error dumping make vars: Failed to parse make line: "value of ABC is kds"*

So while I am able to see that the value of the variable ABC=kds, I am not able to compile the code. Why is this so ?

Please note that the variable ABC is not defined in abc.mk and is being passed on from some different ".mk" file called by "abc.mk"

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error generated by make.  Something is trying to "dump make vars" which probably means it's trying to run `make -p` or similar then parsing the output, and when it comes across this line in the output, which is not a valid make line, it complains as you see above.  With the information you've provided here there's no way for us to know what is giving this error.

You will have to either change this output to look like a make command, such as:

```
$(info # value of ABC is $(ABC))
```

which then prints a line like this:

```
# value of ABC is kids
```

which should be parsed without error, as a comment, by whatever facility is trying to find make variable values, or else figure out what is trying to obtain the variable values and stop it from happening.

Comment: I came across the exact error. I tried your advice, adding "#", but the error still happened, no luck

Comment: See the first paragraph in my answer.